# Why Ruby and Python long division differs from GMP and Java BigInteger?

Tags: java, python, ruby, gmp, bignum

I'm developing a Big Integer class(didactic purpose) and I have been using Ruby to generate test cases. My class fails in the following test:

```
a = -48197174570431531987668852939807674377435188974148779416366905274642031729688518691
b = 4322669160730708444058642850762359547515258361061655693150034467061
a / b = -11149864303351921    # Ruby answer
```

I could not find the bug in my code so I tried to verify the result with other tools and surprise :o.

GMP, Java BigInteger and my class coincides with this results:

```
11149864303351920
-11149864303351920
```

But Ruby and Python coincides with this:

```
-11149864303351921
11149864303351920
```

Can somebody explain why this behavior?, Please.

Comment: I think you are asking why the negative result is one less in Python and Ruby.  In Python, integer division floors, [here is why](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the arguments to integer division are not both positive, a decision must be made for rounding of the quotient and sign of the remainder. GMP supports floor division (f_div...), ceiling division (c_div...), and truncating division (t_div...).

Using gmpy2 to access GMP via Python,

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> a = -48197174570431531987668852939807674377435188974148779416366905274642031729688518691
>>> b = 4322669160730708444058642850762359547515258361061655693150034467061
>>> gmpy2.f_divmod(a,b)
(mpz(-11149864303351921), mpz(1542354793066875276328139562907995977816446564586050094773477055490))
>>> gmpy2.c_divmod(a,b)
(mpz(-11149864303351920), mpz(-2780314367663833167730503287854363569698811796475605598376557411571))
>>> gmpy2.t_divmod(a,b)
(mpz(-11149864303351920), mpz(-2780314367663833167730503287854363569698811796475605598376557411571))
>>> help(gmpy2.f_divmod)
f_divmod(x, y) -> (quotient, remainder)

Return the quotient and remainder of x divided by y. The quotient
is rounded towards -Inf (floor rounding) and the remainder will
have the same sign as y. x and y must be integers.

>>> help(gmpy2.c_divmod)
c_divmod(x, y) -> (quotient, remainder)

Return the quotient and remainder of x divided by y. The quotient
is rounded towards +Inf (ceiling rounding) and the remainder will
have the opposite sign of y. x and y must be integers.

>>> help(gmpy2.t_divmod)
t_divmod(x, y) -> (quotient, remainder)

Return the quotient and remainder of x divided by y. The quotient
is rounded towards zero (truncation) and the remainder will have
the same sign as x. x and y must be integers.
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with integer division.  python 2.x (and, I assume, ruby, though I'm not an expert there) do integer division by default.  if you do this in python:

```
from __future__ import division

a = -48197174570431531987668852939807674377435188974148779416366905274642031729688518691
b = 4322669160730708444058642850762359547515258361061655693150034467061

print int(a/b)
```

you'll see the answer you're expecting.

note that this behaviour is default in python 3+, and that the `from __future__` import is only available in python 2.2+.

Here's some more info. on integer division, courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division) :)

**edit:**

As Steve Rumbalski points out, the significant difference is the way in which the rounding takes place.  Python's integer division rounds towards negative infinity, instead of towards zero (such that -0.2 becomes -1).  Forcing floating point ("true") division and then casting to `int` at the end, as I have done above, means that the rounding is done differently, and that's why my example above gets the "correct" answer.

Comment: -1.  It doesn't look like he is looking for a floating point answer.  If that is true, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- I thought the OP was looking for an explanation of the discrepancy between GMP, Java and his own class on the one hand, and his Python and Ruby tests on the other.  The correct answer is as I have indicated:  that the Python and Ruby examples are using integer division.  Isn't that right?

Comment: Look at the results he gave.  He is fine with the integer result.  If you look at java's BigInteger, the result of division is another BigInteger.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- I see your point now, and you're quite right.  I've updated my answer a little.

Comment: Still incorrect.  Python 3's integer division is the same as Python 2's, it is just spelled differently (`//` vs `/`).